# Edit the values from a row in the HTML table

Tags: django, django-forms, django-tables2

I have a table that looks like that:

```html
       {% for item in records %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form action="{% url 'update_record'%}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
              <input  type="text" class="title" value="{{ item.title }}" size="20" maxlength="30"  />
              <input type="hidden" value={{ item.id }} name="new_title" />
              <input type="submit" value="edit" />
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="result" value="{{ item.results }}" size="10" maxlength="20" readonly />
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Both fields (title, result) have values already but I am trying to edit their value and then send the new title value to my Django view :

```py
@csrf_exempt
def update_record(request):
    # do things with the new title value
    sleep(3)
    return redirect('profile')
```

and here is my urls.py , in case it is helpful in any way:

```py
    urlpatterns = [url(r'^update_record/', views.update_record, name='update_record'),]
```

I tried switching between post and get methods , using AJAX, and almost anything related I could find but nothing seems to work . The current code doesn't produce any errors but I don't see the fields at the "request.POST" dictionary.

Any method would be highly appreciated because I don't know what to try at this point except analytical Ajax classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

For a field to appear in the `request.POST` dictionary the input field needs a `name` attribute.

```py
<form action="{% url 'update_record'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="item_new_title" type="text" class="title" value="{{ item.title }}" size="20" maxlength="30"  />
    <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="{{ item.id }}"  />
    <input type="submit" value="edit" />
</form>
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your form but I've added/changed the `name` attribute of the inputs to `item_new_title` and `item_id`, as an example.

With this form you should be able to get the value of both fields using their `name` attribute as the key.

```py
def update_record(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        item_id = request.POST.get('item_id')
        item_new_title = request.POST.get('item_new_title')
        # do things with the new title value

    return redirect('profile')
```